# Is it possible to copy a (.ISO) file that lives on an NTFS file-system within a VMDK file to the datastore VMFS using ESX SSH terminal?

Tags: ssh, vmware-esx, ntfs, iso, vmfs

I have several .ISO DVD backup files stored on a virtualized Win2008 server. Is there a simple way to mount the NTFS partition stored in a VMDK file using the ESX SSH terminal so that I can copy it directly to the datastore VMFS or must I SFTP the files from the Win2008 machine to the ESX host?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest path would be to install the vSphere client in the guest Windows 2008 operating system, then upload the .ISO images to the destination datastore through the client.

Comment: yes, that works, but at least in my setup it goes through te physical network switch. ESX host is connected via 100 Mbit, so that means the speed won't be more than 4 MB/s (data has to travel 2x through this 100 Mbit link).

Answer (score -1):

I have little experience with VMware ESX, but would [this](http://communities.vmware.com/message/925334#925334) work for you? Something like

```
vmware-mount /PATH/TO/disk.vmdk /mnt/vmdk
```

As explained in the referenced thread, you need VMware's [Disk Development Kit](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vddk/) for this.

Comment: Your anwer really needs more context.  It should still be useful if that link dies.